# How to stop tags being added to an array once limit is reached?

Tags: jquery, html, tag-it

I’ve tried setting a limit on the amount of tag’s I can insert into the box using:

```
tagLimit: 2,
```

Although this stops you entering more than 2 into the box, it still adds them to the ‘sampleTags’ array. Would anyone know how to prevent it adding to the array once the limits reached?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/137/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the afterTagAdded event provided by tagit and move your code pushing the values into the array there. This way your code will only be executed when a tag is really added:

Your Code

```
  // When the user clicks submit
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var inp = $('#tagInput').val();
    $('#tagInput').val('');
    $('#tags').tagit('createTag', inp);
    sampleTags.push(inp);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Remove the line with "sampleTags.push(inp);"

Add the following code to tagit function (see afterTagAdded event):

```
// When the user clicks submit
  $('#tags').tagit({
    availableTags: sampleTags,
    tagLimit: 2,
    afterTagRemoved: function(evt, ui) {
        console.log(ui.tagLabel)
      for(var i = 0; i < sampleTags.length; i++) {
        if (sampleTags[i] == ui.tagLabel) {
          sampleTags.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    },
    afterTagAdded: function(evt, data){
        sampleTags.push(data.tagLabel);
    }
  });
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/142/

**UPDATE:**

To answer the comment. Use "onTagLimitExceeded" to give feedback when tagLimit is reached. Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/144/

```
    afterTagAdded: function(evt, data){
        sampleTags.push(data.tagLabel);
    },
    onTagLimitExceeded: function(evt, data){
        alert('Tag limit reached!');
    }
```

You can find a list of all events on the tag-it github page here: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: Thank you for your answer, once the limits reached. How would I display a maximum limit message. Would this go in the same place?

Comment: No the code would not be executed if you add the 3rd tag. But there is an other event for this case. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add an if to your submit function wich checks the length of the  sampleTags variable

```
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    if(sampleTags.length < 2){
      var inp = $('#tagInput').val();
      $('#tagInput').val('');
      $('#tags').tagit('createTag', inp);
      sampleTags.push(inp);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Ive updated your Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uVxXg/139/)

I Hope this works for you :)